# Bathroom Subfloor

Tags: subfloor

I need 1 1/2" of subfloor in my bathroom to meet other floors. Can I use two 3/4" OSB? And will that be strong enough for a freestanding tub? The Joists are 2x10 and average out to 16 oc (self built, I don't think he was too concerned about spacing). Do the layers run the same way, with offsetting joints, or opposite? We are putting down Premium Vinyl planks.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. I presume  you're already down to the joists; a picture would help us understand your situation.

Comment: Knowing that it's a wet environment, I'd avoid OSB. Use plywood, if you're on joists; ply or some sort of cement board if you're coming up from an existing subfloor. Stagger the joints if you're doing multiple layers.